# How do I import a JSON string into R as a dataframe when vectors in the JSON are different lengths?

Tags: json, r

I have the following JSON stored locally on my PC.

```
{
     "modprod": "1",
     "values": ["top opt", "5 adjustable shelves", "stl top", "gls door", "Bookcase"],
     "common": ["lam top", "wood top"]
}
```

I want to read this into R as a dataframe that looks like...

```
modprod,feature,common
1,top_opt,0
1,5 adjustable shelves,0
1,stl top,0
1,gls door,0
1,bookcase,0
1,lam top,1
1,wood top,1
```

I have searched extensively on Stack Overflow, but can find no solution. The problems I'm running into:

- Obviously the lengths of "modprod", "values", and "common" are all different. In this case there is one entry for "modprod", five entries for "values", and two entries for "common".

I believe I have demonstrated exactly the starting and ending points. Can someone help me please?

Comment: You haven't described the logic of how the data goes into the data frame...For example, where are the 0's coming from, and are the values from the "common" object supposed to just be appended to the values from the "values" object in a single column called "feature"?

Comment: Apologies on the lack of clarity. The column called "feature" would have all the values from the "values" object. In some cases, the "common" object contains values that also exist in the "values" object. When this is the case, the column called "common" simply serves as a binary flag/identifier that the feature in a given row was a value in the "common" object. In set terms, the "values" object is the union of many sets, while the "common" object is the intersection of those sets. I simply want to call out in the column called "common" when a given feature exists in the intersection of sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

fromJSON('{
     "modprod": "1",
     "values": ["top opt", "5 adjustable shelves", "stl top", "gls door", "Bookcase"],
     "common": ["lam top", "wood top"]
}') -> js

data_frame(
  modprod = rep(js$modprod, length(js$values) + length(js$common)),
  feature = c(js$values, js$common),
  common = c(rep(0, length(js$values)), rep(1, length(js$common)))
)
## # A tibble: 7 × 3
##   modprod              feature common
##     <chr>                <chr>  <dbl>
## 1       1              top opt      0
## 2       1 5 adjustable shelves      0
## 3       1              stl top      0
## 4       1             gls door      0
## 5       1             Bookcase      0
## 6       1              lam top      1
## 7       1             wood top      1
```

but you shld consider being clearer in your question and add a larger example